# Background Position inline style with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I've been trying to place a block of rendered jsx to the right side of the first block for the past 2 hours. I can't seem to get it right. I tried using `marginTop`, `marginLeft` , etc., but those didn't work. I looked it up, and found that I could substitute with `backgroundPosition`. It hasn't worked though. Here's my current line: `<div style={{backgroundPosition: -400 -100}}>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the values to strings.

eg:

```
 <div style={{backgroundPosition: '-400px -100px'}}>
```

The object you are passing to the `style` attribute should be a plain javascript object - and needs to be valid as one.

Comment: `<div style={{marginLeft: 290, marginTop: -600, padding: 10}}>` This actually worked, but thank you anyways :p

Comment: @Dan If this hasn't worked at all, then why have you accepted it?

Comment: @FaisalAlvi I believe it led me to the answer, which i commented (if anyone wanted to know how to do the same thing)

Comment: You are correct Dan, but I would suggest that we should not accept answers because most of the users only see the accepted mark and use the code, they don't read comments. Well, let's close the chat. :)